# Static IP set in /e/n/interfaces, Debian 9 takes DHCP

Tags: debian, ip, ethernet, dhcp, static-ip

Objective: Set box (fileserver, x over ssh, backup location) with static IP 192.168.1.192.
Router does not have  static-by-mac functionality.

Problem: lines in /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto enp0s10
iface enp0s10 inet static
gateway 192.168.1.254
gateway...
```

or

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static...
```

both return errors, and both grab DHCP address.

dmesg shows:

```
enp0s10: renamed from eth0
```

uname:

```
Linux $hostname 4.9.0-3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.30-2 (2017-06-12) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'm at a loss as to how to set static IP. Not sure if I'm being retard or Something is broken/has changed with  latest version debian new naming of eth>enp.
Can it be done by MAC in /e/n/interfaces? is there another way?

Comment: **What errors** do they return?

Comment: You can try to set hwaddress [this way](https://serverfault.com/questions/339989/why-does-debian-squeeze-forget-its-static-ip-address-and-seek-a-dhcp-lease/897705#897705)

Answer (score 0):

Is NetworkManager or some other process running causing it to also try a DHCP lease?

Try to see if either is running, and if they are maybe reconfigure it to not come online or otherwise use static addressing:

```
$ ps aux | grep dhclient
root     24399  0.0  0.0  79712  7712 ?        S    01:07   0:00 /sbin/dhclient -d -q -sf /usr/libexec/nm-dhcp-helper -pf /var/run/dhclient-bridge0.pid -lf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-591db50f-fdad-45ee-9766-1f117f9df0a7-bridge0.lease -cf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-bridge0.conf bridge0
```